# Why DoModal() on object of CFileDialog crashes on second call?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

happens only if I have filter whose string is loaded from an resource ID.

e.g.

```
CString szFilter;
szFilter.LoadString(IDC_ALLFILES);
```

where `IDC_ALLFILES = "All files (*.*)|*.*||"`

when I try to do `DoModal()` on same instance of `CFileDialaog`, it crashes on second time.

I have created a small sample project to simulate the exact behavior.

1. First thing I have done is declared a CFileDialog pointer as follows:

   ```
   class CFeatureDialogFileDlg : public CDialog
   {

   private:
       CFileDialog* m_pFileDialog;
   ```

   }
2. I have two buttons 'Set Flags' and 'Open features' as follows:

   ```
   void CFeatureDialogFileDlg::OnBnClickedButtonSetFlags()
           {
               static CString szFilter;
                szFilter.LoadStringW(IDC_ALLFILES);

            m_pFileDialog = new CFileDialog(TRUE,NULL,NULL,OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_NOCHANGEDIR,szFilter);
           }

   void CFeatureDialogFileDlg::OnBnClickedButtonOpenFeatures()
   {



       if(m_pFileDialog->DoModal() == IDOK){}

   }
   ```

Now,

I just click 'Set Flags' to create a new object on heap.
then I click on 'Open Features' to call DoModal().

First time it gets called properly. 
But second time when I click 'Open Features' without clicking on 'Set Flags', I get an error dialog "Debug Assertion Failed in file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\dlgfile.cpp"

if I click 'ignore' I get "Encountered an improper argument" dialog.

Comment: Please read this: [ask]. And please tell us exactly how and where it crashes and show us the call stack. And show at least the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: You can load a string from the `STRINGTABLE` and use it with your `CFileDialog`. But how are you setting the filter? In the constructor or with the `m_ofn` object? Please show sufficient code, including your resource value.

Comment: That should be `"All Files (*.*)|*.*|"` but that's probably not related to your mysterious error.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk77e5e7.aspx#cfiledialog__cfiledialog you have to use `||` to terminate the end of the range of filters. Or was that a typo? :)

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Yes the convention is use `||` for the last line in the list. A single `|` will work too, because `|` is converted to `NUL`, and C-string ends with `NUL`, so the output will end with double zeros, but that's sort of cryptic.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: That's correct for flat string lists. The filter string, however, is a list of **pairs** of strings. The first `|` delimits the final pair from the sentinel, and the second `|` delimits the sentinel display string from the pattern. The trailing NUL character terminates the (zero-length) sentinel pattern. While a single `|` may work, it isn't correct according to the contract.

Comment: I blame the documentation for the confusion, though. Had it said: *"... is a list of pairs of strings, terminated by a pair of zero-length strings"* it would have established the same restriction, but with much more helpful context. I first came across this interpretation when reading [What is the format of a double-null-terminated string with no strings?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091008-00/?p=16443), and it stuck with me.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question. I have edited it for better understanding of the problem.

Comment: That's a debug assertion. Did you actually try to read the dialog? You are a developer. You are expected to at least read and comprehend messages. Click the button that takes you right into your debugger, and you'll **instantly** know, which precondition didn't hold. I'm not sure what makes you believe that [you were a software engineer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9397512/vivek-swami) either.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes I have read a dialog and I know its an debut assertion. I have mentioned that in a question . Second thing, I tried to also debug into dlgfile.cpp and found  SetFileTypes gives an error E_UNEXPECTED on second call to DoModal.

Finally, instead of giving motivation talk here. You should have said something helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Ok. then, here's something helpful. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your replies.

I have recognized the cause of the problem.

1. In mfc 9, two extra parameters were introduced i.e. dwSize and bVistaStyle for CFileDialog.
2. Because of bVistaStyle = TRUE, we call new Vista style dialog box and multiple calls to CFileDialog::DoModal for the same instance of a CFileDialog generates ASSERT.
3. Below line gives **E_UNEXPECTED** on second time call to DoModal()

   HRESULT hr;

   hr = (static_cast(m_pIFileDialog))->SetFileTypes(nFilterCount, pFilter);

from file dlgfile.cpp which is at location C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc

Explanation can be found on https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/dk77e5e7(v=vs.90).aspx  in Note section.

Possible solutions are:

1. Use Old style dialog box by changing the default parameter bVistaStyle = FALSE
2. Create a new dialog each time and delete it.

We can not call DoModal() multile times if bVistaStyle = TRUE